# Converting to bool and using eval to give a checkbox checked giving a error

Tags: html, asp.net, checkbox

I've got this checkbox and I'm trying to eval a boolean value to it, I'm getting an error saying "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types. ".
Here's my checkbox. Let me know if I should provide something else.

```
      <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CurrSadlDepositClient" disabled="true" aria-describedby="lblSadlDepositClient" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("SadlDepositClient")) %>' />
```

Comment: Then your database query is returning `SadlDepositClient` as a `null` value. And `null` cannot be converted (as the error message indicates)

Comment: But I tried pasting this on a label and it gives either True or False

Comment: Maybe, that particular row did have a valid value. Point is you should check the source data.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my Checked="" I got the result I wanted.

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CurrSadlDepositClient" disabled="true" aria-describedby="lblSadlDepositClient" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("SadlDepositClient").ToString() == "" ? "false" : Eval("SadlDepositClient").ToString()) %>' />
```